# Why is my Javascript theme-color function is being called but still not working properly?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, themes

When I go into the elements, I can see that the theme color is refreshing, its just not changing. So instead of theme-light changing to theme-dark, it's theme-light changing to theme-light.
[the screenshot was taken mid click while the "theme-dark" changed to "theme-dark"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S4Er.jpg)
CSS:

```
               html, body {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .theme-light {
                    --color-secondary: #fbfbfe;
                }

                .theme-dark {
                    --color-secondary: #243133;
                }

                .container {
                    display: flex;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    background: var(--color-secondary);
                    flex-direction: column;
                    justify-content: center;
                    align-items: center;
                }
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section>

            <h3>Switch Left Right</h3>
            <label class="switch switch-left-right" onclick="toggleTheme()">
                <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="Light" data-off="Dark"></span> <span class="switch-handle"></span>
            </label>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script>
        // function to set a given theme/color-scheme
        function setTheme(themeName) {
            localStorage.setItem('theme', themeName);
            document.documentElement.className = themeName;
        }

        // function to toggle between light and dark theme
        function toggleTheme() {
            if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
                setTheme('theme-light');
            } else {
                setTheme('theme-dark');
            }
        }

        // Immediately invoked function to set the theme on initial load
        (function () {
            if (localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark') {
                setTheme('theme-dark');
            } else {
                setTheme('theme-light');
            }
        })();
    </script>
```

And also, when I click the very edge of the span, it works properly. I have no idea why this is like that. Could I be overlapping the function which would make it change the theme twice?
Any help would be great.

Comment: if (localStorage.getItem('theme') == '' || localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'theme-dark')
Update your condition like that, I think first time you are not initialized theme variable

Comment: You also need to refresh page

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct
But Class Container, it does not exist in html code.
if you need more details about variable css check this link [var css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)